# Cookies disappear after setting them in Microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set cookies that are permanent in Microsoft edge. They last only until I close the browser. Yes I have cookies enabled. Here is some code I found from a while ago:

```
var cookieHandler = {
setCookie : function(name, value, days, time) 
{
    var expires = "";
    if(days)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (time || (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
},
getCookie : function(name) 
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while(c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
        {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }
        if(c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
        {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }   
    }
    return null;
},
eraseCookie : function(name) 
{   
    document.cookie = name + '=; Max-Age=-99999999999;';  
}
};
```

Yeah when I reopen the browser my cookies are gone. Does anyone have working code for cookies in Microsoft edge?

Edit:
I'm using the file:/// origin.

Comment: Check this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9160757/

Comment: Okay, I will. Oh too bad they say "won't fix". Is there any other way I can make the browser save data in the "file:///" origin? I've tried local storage but that doesn't work.